# Display divider between the elements

Tags: html, css

I am creating a nav menu. The nav (`.nav`) has `li` which will be used to navigate to different page. Each of the `li`'s are floated and has the width of 20% to use all the screen width.

Now I need to display divider between the `li`'s inside the `.nav` ul li

[image]

I tried using border-left after the first li, but since all of the li are floated in percentage to cover the screen width, the last `li` goes down. And there is no outline-left/right like the border-left/right.

How do I display/make a divider between the `li`'s without disrupting the width of the li so as all the `nav li` will be in one line?

html:

```
<div id="footer-wrapper">
  <div id="footer">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-compass"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </li>
      <span class="clear_both"></span>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#footer-wrapper {
    background: #00A7FF;
}


.nav {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.nav li:hover {
    background: #393232;
    color: white;
}

#footer-wrapper #footer .nav li {
    width: 20%;
}
```

**Update**

Demo at [codepen](http://codepen.io/aamus/pen/YwGoWJ).

Comment: @LaljiTadhani here it is [codepen](http://codepen.io/aamus/pen/YwGoWJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this used to  this

**[Sibling Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)** and **[:after](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)** and `position` `relative` define your `li` tag than used to `li + li:after` tag and assign value `content` , `position`, `left`, `top`, `bottom`, `border` as like this

```
li + li:after
```

**Demo Code here**

```css
#footer-wrapper {
    background: #00A7FF;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.nav {
    list-style: none;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;float:left;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
  position:relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.nav li:hover {
    background: #393232;
    color: white;
}
.nav li + li:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  border-left:solid 1px black;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}

#footer-wrapper #footer .nav li {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-wrapper">
  <div id="footer">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-compass"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </li>
      <span class="clear_both"></span>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did `.nav li + li:after` styling solve it? Could you explain it please? @Rohit Azad

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="footer-wrapper">
  <div id="footer">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>a
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
      </li>
      <li>b
        <i class="fa fa-compass"></i>
      </li>
      <li>c
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      </li>
      <li>d
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
      </li>
      <li>e
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </li>
      <span class="clear_both"></span>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<style>

#footer-wrapper {
    background: #00A7FF;
}


.nav {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.nav li:hover {
    background: #393232;
    color: white;
}

#footer-wrapper #footer .nav li {
    width: 20%;
}
.nav li:before {
content: " | ";
}

.nav li:first-child:before {
content: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/06k7r2kr/2/

`<div id="footer-wrapper">
     <div id="footer">
         <ul class="nav">
         <li>
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
         </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-compass"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </li>
      <span class="clear_both"></span>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>`
it is working
use this jsfiddle

Comment: I can't see no divider in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach:
**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/LybptL4d/2/)**

My Changes:

I added  `border-left: 1px solid #e0e;` in  `.nav li {.. }` so divider ( border ) shows and finally add `border-left: none;` in first `li` so first `li` has no left divider.

```
.nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s;
    border-left: 1px solid #e0e;
}

.nav li:first-child{
  border-left: none;    
}
```

here is all code

```css
#footer-wrapper {
    background: #00A7FF;
}


.nav {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s;
    border-left: 1px solid #e0e;
}

.nav li:first-child{
  border-left: none; 
}
.nav li:hover {
    background: #393232;
    color: white;
}

#footer-wrapper #footer .nav li {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-wrapper">
  <div id="footer">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-compass"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </li>
      <span class="clear_both"></span>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```